# Having trouble implementing random background images

Tags: php, html, css

I'd like to get this random background image coding to work: http://css-tricks.com/snippets/php/randomize-background-image/

I've double checked file names, paths, all the code and the instructions. I think there's something I don't understand.

You can see the page here:
http://agentboris.com/newwebsite/index.html

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Make your file to .php or call the php-script with javascript/jQuery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your file at http://agentboris.com/newwebsite/index.html is in .html, it should be in .php for you be able to use php code from tutorial.

Try with this simple code (don't forget to save your index file as php extension):

```
  <?php
  $bg = array('bg-01.jpg', 'bg-02.jpg', 'bg-03.jpg', 'bg-04.jpg', 'bg-05.jpg', 'bg-06.jpg', 'bg-07.jpg' ); // array of filenames

  $i = rand(0, count($bg)-1); // generate random number size of the array
  $selectedBg = "$bg[$i]"; // set variable equal to which random filename was chosen
?>


 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Tests purposes</title>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>
        <style type="text/css">
        <!--
        body{
        background: url(images/<?php echo $selectedBg; ?>) no-repeat;
        }
        -->
        </style>
    </head>

    <body>


    </body>
</html>
```